# how can install webcolors on odoo15

Tags: python, odoo

How can i prevent this error when i install module give me error bellow:

File "/mnt/extra-addons/bi_all_in_one_purchase/models/invoice_order_excel_report.py", line 6, in 
from webcolors import hex_to_rgb, rgb_to_hex
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 654, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webcolors'

How to solve the error above i tried by some ways but did not get solution

Comment: Does the `bi_all_in_one_purchase` module have a `requirement.txt` file?

Comment: yes when I purchased bi_all_in_one_purchase  to install appear the error

Comment: Try to install the requirements  using the Python running Odoo 15

Comment: all ready installed but empty file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest file of you module, you can add this line:

```py
install_requires=[
'webcolors'
],
```

or in `src/user/requirements.txt`, add the line:

```
webcolors
```

If it has no effect, you could use the Terminal to execute these bash-commands to investigate the error message:

```
cd src/user    
pip3 install requirements.txt
```